# Undo checkout in tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I mistakenly checked out several projects, but I only need 1 of them. How do I undo a checkout in tortoise SVN?

Answer (score 1):

Simply deleting the local copies of the folders you mistakenly checked out should correct the issue. This will work if each project is in it's own directory.